# center a panel in a box layout row in java

Tags: java, swing, layout, layout-manager, boxlayout

I have this code below to create a page inside of a tab.
I want each layout in one row of the overall box layout but i want the elements to stay in their original size and not expand to fill the width of the overall window. does anyone know what lines of code i need to change or what is the best way of doing this?! The image attached shows what it looks like at the moment

[image]

```
public void createPage4() {
    panel4 = new JPanel();
    panel4.setLayout(new BoxLayout(panel4, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
    navigatePanel = new JPanel();
    navigatePanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(navigatePanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    previousButton.setText("Previous");
    previousButton.setEnabled(false);
    navigatePanel.add(previousButton);
    navigatePanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
    indexTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    navigatePanel.add(indexTextField);
    navigatePanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
    ofLabel.setText("of");
    navigatePanel.add(ofLabel);
    navigatePanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
    maxTextField.setHorizontalAlignment(JTextField.CENTER);
    maxTextField.setEditable(false);
    navigatePanel.add(maxTextField);
    navigatePanel.add(Box.createHorizontalStrut(10));
    nextButton.setText("Next");
    nextButton.setEnabled(false);
    navigatePanel.add(nextButton);
    panel4.add(navigatePanel);
    displayPanel = new JPanel();
    displayPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2, 4, 4));
    firstNameLabel.setText("First Name:");
    displayPanel.add(firstNameLabel);
    displayPanel.add(firstNameTextField);
    lastNameLabel.setText("Last Name:");
    displayPanel.add(lastNameLabel);
    displayPanel.add(lastNameTextField);
    panel4.add(displayPanel);
}
```

image

[image]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

- [BoxLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/box.html) accepting `Min, Max and PreferredSize` that came from `JComponents`

> I want each layout in one row of the overall box layout but i want the elements to stay in their original size and not expand to fill the width of the overall window

- I'd be to use proper `LayoutManage`r, [FlowLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html) accepting only `PreferredSize`, and/or all `JComponents` layed by [GridBagLayout without defininitions of GridBagConstraints](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html) stays unchanged on containers resize
- doesn't make me sence (my view) for why reason (sure this is your job), but for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way is to add your `panel4` to an other panel that uses `GridBagLayout` and then add *that* panel to the container. Then it will be centered and nothing will stretch on resize.

```
JPanel centeredPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
centeredPanel.add(panel4);    // add this panel to the container
```

You should also construct the textfields with a specified number of columns, like

```
indexTextField = new JTextField(20);
```